# Should tags be added for each security patch, such as supee-6788?

Tags: discussion, tags

It seems reasonable to have tags for each security patch, but it doesn't look like they've been used so far.  Any objections to tagging patch-specific questions with a tag like [supee-6788](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supee-6788)?

Answer (score 2):

Since the tag [supee-6788](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supee-6788) has been introduced, there are 70 questions, seraching for "supee-6788" yields 233 results. So individual patches, at least those with bc breaks or other complications could be a topic big enough to warrant its own tag.

But for previous patches there were not that many questions, even for the shoplift patch SUPEE-5344, there are only 63 search results, and for SUPEE-6285 with the infamous "access denied" errors, there are only 61 seach results.

As a conclusion, I would say that an individual tag for each patch is not necessary and there is no real benefit for it.

#### Remember the reason for tags:

They should make it easy to find questions that you can answer. So for example, if you are an expert for the Magento import, you can follow the [import](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/import) tag (4 followers). Can you be an expert for a specific patch? Maybe, but it seems like that's too specific for anybody to follow:

The tag [supee-6788](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supee-6788) has 0 followers, the tag [patches](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/patches) has 2 followers, the tag [security](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) has 4 followers.

Comment: I'm not sure if subscribing to tags is very popular at all. Even the most popular tag 'catalog' has only 63 followers.
I personally like tags to add them to my favorite tags.

Comment: And yes, I agree that for example supee-6788 should have its own tag. Might not be that important for less complicated patches.

Comment: Anna your point about tag subscriptions is important though it may have some other implications.  Party I think the UI of subscribing is not as easy as it could be (you have to "edit" your list of favorites then enter the tag manually.  Before I worked this out it was easier for me to just use my chrome InoReader plugin to have it figure out the RSS feed for the tag page and follow along in the same reader I use for all the other stuff I follow. SE is improving the UI and will continue to do so. Also, as more users become active and naturally specialize I think it will be more commonly used.

Comment: None of that may really change anything important about how we analyze you or Fabian's input, but I think tags are really young and not fully matured as tech & also not broadly understood even on SO & Server Fault so our opinions are likely to change both as they become more widespread across the growing SE network and mores specifically as our own Comunity becomes more familiar with their behavior then how we can incorporate them into our own workflows.